# Static date picker change background color of a week row

Tags: material-ui, mui-x

I need to change the week row background color of the StaticDatePicker of MUI. Depending if is past the current week (as orange color) and the current week (as blue color). Is there any way that i can override the class or some hide attribute that i need to add?

If its possible to override can someone tell how to override it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you inspect the HTML for the `StaticDatePicker`, you will see that each week/row on the popout contains the `.MuiDayCalendar-weekContainer` class. Within each row, the days contain the `.MuiPickersDay-root` class and today contains the `MuiPickersDay-today` class. You can use these classes along with the `:has` pseudo-selector to style all of the days in the current week. Note that `:has` [is not supported in all browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=has) so this may not be the best solution:

```
<StaticDatePicker sx={{
  '& .MuiDayCalendar-weekContainer': {
    '.MuiPickersDay-root': {
      // Do your custom styling for all weeks other than this week here
    }
  }

  '& .MuiDayCalendar-weekContainer:has(> .MuiPickersDay-today)': {
    '.MuiPickersDay-root': {
      // Do your custom styling for this week here. The :has selector is more specific than the general styling you did above so this should override those styles
    }
  },
}} />
```

Comment: It was necessary to update @mui/x-date-pickers in order to this work. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

If you want change the color of WeekDays Label you can try :

```
<StaticDatePicker sx={{

     "& .MuiDayCalendar-weekDayLabel": {color: "red",},
}} />
```

[image]
eg. :